# Socket close timing

Tags: android, sockets, timing

I have what appears to be a timing problem between a client (Galaxy Nexus) and a custom server since upgrading from Ice Cream Sandwich to Jelly Bean.  Here is the general flow:

1. Client opens socket, issues HTTP get to server
2. Server accepts, starts new thread, responds with HTTP header and 200 OK.
3. Server writes (binary) file to socket.
4. Client reads data from socket and saves to a file.
5. After server thread writes all data, it closes the socket, and terminates

This has worked well over the past several months prior to the Jelly Bean update.  Since the update the binary transfer succeeds about 70% of the time.  The remaining 30% fails
when 'serverSocket.getInputStream().read' returns a -1 indicating the end of stream has been reached.  No data has been read, no error exceptions raised, nothing in logcat.

The possibility of a timing problem arises when I change the server behavior in step #5.  The thread was closing the socket after the write with the observed problems.  If I remove the socket close, terminate the thread after the write, and let the OS eventually close the socket then it seems to work all the time.

I used tcpdump and WireShark to look at the packets in both the successful and failed cases.  In the failed case a socket is closed in a few milli-seconds while in the successful case the socket is closed is a quarter or more of a second.  The net of this is that any delay we cause in the socket closing improves our chances for success.

If anyone has any suggestions with what we may be doing to cause this problem or suggestions on how to narrow down the problem please feel free to respond.  I can add code samples if required.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like that when the server ask for the connection close, the socket is immediatly closed. Maybe the default ocket linger's time has changed between version ???

Try setting the socket linger's time using:

```
socket.setSoLinger(boolean on, int timeout);
```

to have the server waiting some time before close channel if some data still waiting to be sent.

If this doesn't solve, you can change your flow above to:

...

4.Client reads data from socket and saves to a file.

5.Client send confirmation to server.

6.Server close connection.

--EDITED--
A gracefull way to achive the above without additional TCP data packets traveling for the closing confirmation is:

when server finish writing to the socket calls:

```
socket.shutdownOutput();
```

when client socket.read() returns -1, client calls:

```
socket.close();
```

This ensures that client is informed that all data has been sent, and sender will wait for the socket closure protocol to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We tried the linger with no difference.  It did help prove our retry code though!  Adding a confirmation is something we are trying to avoid.  If we have to we will but for now we will pursue other solutions.

Comment: The setTcpNoDelay(), I believe, will have no effect.  Our test case is small and is encompassed in a single TCP packet with PSH. Also, our understanding on an HTTP get, the server is responsible for first closing the connection.  Though not against the proposed solution it does not meet the standard(?).  Still trying to understand if its our implementation or something else.

Comment: @Dent Anything is possible on a newish platform, but adding the shutdownOutput() should have no effect. The client is already receiving a FIN, and all that shutdownOutput() does is send one. Similarly, changing the linger time should have no effect either. The server had already written all the data and sent the FIN: having it wait while the residue is sent doesn't really accomplish anything. I also agree that setTcpNoDelay() should have no effect either. I would be looking for a platform bug here.